# When someone blasphemes, can a person who witnesses it kill him and become a hero or martyr if he is executed for murder?

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, punishment, martyr, blasphemy

There's a hot topic in my country: One person who murdered his boss for the sake of blasphemy has been hanged after 6 years.  From the [BBC](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-35693767):

> Thousands of Pakistanis have turned out for the funeral of a former bodyguard executed for killing Punjab's governor over his opposition to blasphemy laws.
>
> Qadri was hailed as a hero by Islamists for the 2011 killing of Salman Taseer, who wanted to reform the strict laws.

I was put forward a story which I don't know the origin of: It says that one Muslim and one Jew went to Prophet Muhammad (PBUH), with some issue and Prophet Muhammad (PBUH), made the decision in favor of the Jew, which made the Muslim angry and he went for second opinion to Hazrat Ali. Upon hearing that Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) had made a decision and the Muslim was not ok with it, Hazrat Ali beheaded the Muslim, saying he was a hypocrite.

If that is true, then does this mean that when someone blasphemes, a person who witnesses it can kill him because he made blasphemous remark, and is a hero or martyr if he is executed for murder?

I am confused over this subject, as a murderer was deemed a hero at his funeral in the above example.

Comment: I would recomment you reading a book named الصارم المسلول على شاتم الرسول also translated in english and urdu by darul-salam, besides i am form same country. And this is a huge topic thats why instead of writing answer. I am recommending this book.

Comment: On a side note, there are videos and i an agreed he talked blasphemy i his speeches because of which all this happened, and in his funeral not only common people but ULAMA of all sects took part.

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal In Pakistan, many things happening are unislamic, i am not just talking about a state. I am talking about whole of islam and wanted to know the real story of what i mentioned above.

Comment: Sorry but I'm tying to follow your Post, but can't find a clear cut (maybe it's due to the resistant flu which made me stay at home a few weeks that i have problems to follow your text) so are you looking for an explanation why Muslims accept it if somebody killed somebody else because of blasphemy? And could you provide more information about the story/narration you mentioned?

Comment: @Medi1Saif I only heard of that story about Hazrat (R.A), that i need source of, the point of story was to tell me that just because the muslim could not accept what prophet Muhammad (PBUH) said, and went for a opinion to Ali. Hazrat Ali beheaded him after knowing he came to with a doubt that what Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) mentioned wasn't true. So killing a blasphemy person who did i, is alright in islam because nothing is greater than prophet and no one should disrespect him I want to know if that story is really true.

Comment: Well i remember that i heard something like that, but I'm not sure whom the Sahabi was who was consulted and don't really remember the details therefore i asked whether you could provide some more information to do a research based on that!

Comment: @Medi1Saif i couldn't find it on internet either.

Comment: I found a story in Arabic saying that the consulted sahabi was Omar ibn al Khattab (May Allah be pleased with him) but the fatwa http://fatwa.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=130593 says that this story is weak because of ibn Lahy'ah and because it was a mursal hadith it also pretends to be the reason for revelation of this verse http://legacy.quran.com/4/65, but this doesn't go ahead with sahih hadiths others pretend it's about Verse (4:60)

Comment: Can I see sources in the story of Nofel?

Answer (score 2):

Before we consult ahadith, we will have to see what Quran says on this Topic. After all, a book that tells you how to clean yourself (method of wudu) can not neglect to tell you when you are allowed to take a human life.

Quran is full of disrespectful words that were being used for the prophet at the time. For example we see in Surat Furqan:
25:4
25:5
25:7
25:8
25:9
25:31
25:41

Then it goes on about how other prophets were also ridiculed. Now THIS WAS THE BEST PLACE TO ANNOUNCE DEATH for such people. Instead we see statements like these :

> 25:52 So do not obey the disbelievers, and strive against them with the Qur'an a great striving.
> 33:48 Do not yield to the disbelievers or the hypocrites. Ignore their annoying you. Trust in God. God is your all Sufficient Protector.

Also, we see the only reasons for taking a human life are:

1. Soul for a soul
2. Corruption in the land
3. War against oppression

   Personally, I see this quite in line with the spirit of Islam and the distinction between crime and sin.

Crime is against humanity and need to be punished in this world. We all know what happens in societies that do not have a just law enforcement system.

Sins on the other hand are between Allah and human. And Allah has clearly told us that he will forgive ALL our sins no matter how late in life, as long as we repent and ask for forgiveness. Now if a person is  killed for a sin like blasphemy or apostasy, we are taking away his right of repentance. Did we get a message from Allah telling us that this man will NEVER repent? If not then we have no right to take his life.